# Android soft menu key listener exists?

Tags: android, navbar

I have an issue where if I disable hardware menu buttons (ie back, home, menu). I'm left with a software menu bar on screen. But my previous key down listener for KEYCODE_MENU no longer works on this virtual menu button. Can someone help me with the right key listener for this virtual menu button?

Before the following works on hardware menu button but stops working when I disable hardware buttons and have soft menu button enabled in android:

```
      @Override
      public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
          switch(keycode) {
              case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                  doSomething();
                  return true;
          }
          return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[New versions of Android do not have Menu button at all](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html), although some manufacturers *ahem* *Samsung* keep adding hardware Menu button.

To have Menu button in the navigation bar, that will send Menu keycode, you will have to set targetSdkVersion to 10 in your AndroidManifest.xml, which will make your application look ancient.

You can realistically expect only three hardware buttons (e.g. buttons that will send keycodes) - Back, Volume Up, and Volume Down, and it's bad style to use Volume buttons for anything other than changing sound volume.

Comment: But currently I see 3 buttons on the soft navigation bar. How do I capture the key down event on the soft menu button; the one that looks like 2 boxes.

Comment: This is not a Menu button, this button is to switch between apps. Menu button looked like four horizontal lines on older versions of Android, and looks like three vertical dots on newer versions of Android.

Comment: I'll give KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH  a try tonight. Thanks!

Comment: Haha good luck. Apps cannot receive this keycode - it is intercepted by the system to show recent apps list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one hack, when recent button is hit while an app is running, it puts the app in onPause. So what you can do is, in `onPause()` of your app, reorder tasks and bring your app on top of all tasks. This way you will only experience a glitch when recent apps button is pressed.

place this code in `onPause()`

```
((ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
```

And following permission is needed in order to reorder tasks.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```